# Reading a local text file in javascript synchronuosly

Tags: javascript, file, io, xmlhttprequest

i just want to read a local text file and assign it to a variable. I don't see why this code doesn't work. I have already looked almost in any response on stackoverflow since yesterday and that's the only synchronous way i have found.

Anybody sees the problem ?

```
function readTextFile(file){

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', file);
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
console.log(request);
console.log(request.responseText);
return request.responseText;
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you sending the request? A `return` inside `onreadystatechange` has no meaning. This isn’t synchronous. Why do you want to make it synchronous in the first place?

Comment: I have tried the async, but 'everytime' i got the error undefined, since the execution continues, but the file hasn't been read yet.

Comment: I send it nowhere, just trying simply read a local text file

Comment: Please don’t make it synchronous. Read [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/4642212).

Comment: If you don’t `send` the request, then nothing will happen. Please read the docs on [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), or even better: use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead.

Comment: isn't that supposed to be working with fetch?                                                                         fetch('pathTo/some.csv')
      .then(re =>
        // console.log("in the fetch " + re.text())
        data_array = re.text()
        )

Comment: it's still undefined, eventhough it's in the then part

Comment: You need to return `re.text()` before you can work with the data: `fetch("pathTo/some.csv").then((re) => re.text()).then((data) => console.log(data))`. It’s not possible to use the data in a global variable outside of an asynchronous call.

Comment: *"I don't see why this code doesn't work"* well that call is not synchronous and you can not return from onreadystate so seems like there are a bunch of reasons why it will not work.